# Get data from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

**Project Informations**

- Windows Presentation Foundation Project
- C# as programming language

**Description**

Is it possible to receive data from an user input in `Window1` and show this input in `MainWindow`?

I will open the user input as a file from `Window1` and will show the content of it in the RichTextBox of `MainWindow`.

**Window1**

```xml
<Window x:Name="window1" x:Class="Writer.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Writer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New" Height="130" Width="600" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-2">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Fill="Black"/>
        <Label Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Content="X" Margin="579,5,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" ToolTip="Exit" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Label Content="Select the path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsTabStop="False"/>
        <Button Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFADADAD" Width="45"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow**

```xml
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" x:Class="Writer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Writer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Writer" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="164*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="83*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="203*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Fill="Black"/>
        <Label Content="Writer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Content="_" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="765,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" Focusable="False" ToolTip="Minimize" IsTabStop="False" ClickMode="Press" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="X" Margin="779,5,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" ToolTip="Exit" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" Click="Button_Click"/>
 
        <Menu Margin="0,30,0,114" Height="20">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="New">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/file-added.svg"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open from server"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save as"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close file"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close folder"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Start">
                <MenuItem Header="Font">
                    <MenuItem Header="Font"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Family"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Size"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Bold"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Italic"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Underline"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Strikethrough"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Insert">
                <MenuItem Header="New site"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Layout">
                
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="View">
                
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
        </Menu>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox1" Margin="0,50,0,0" BorderBrush="White" Cursor="Arrow" IsTabStop="False" Grid.RowSpan="3" FontFamily="Segoe UI" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text=""/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: C# or VB.NET? It's unlikely that you program the same class in both languages.

Comment: My program is in C# .

Comment: Basically the answer is probably useless to you. That is because the question is so generic and gives so little details, that the answer can also be generic only and give no details, too. If you like a better answer, please [edit] the question and provide a [mre], i.e. something that we can copy/paste and compile.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a full example

Comment: Ok. I will show you my project code a little bit .

Comment: The [license of code on Stack Overflow is always CC-BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). I don't think you can change that. And the question is: what if you integrate code from my answer into your project? Is that legal? Probably you should mention where this code came from (But I don't care. I'll give it free to you, like CC-0).

Comment: Also, don't deface your question, especially after it has been answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Implement a public method in `Window1` that gives you the data.
Then use the reference to `Window1` and call that method.
If `MainWindow` does not have a reference to `Window1`, give it the reference.

Here's an example. It assumes that you open the second window from within the main window.

<sub>In addition to the CC-BY-SA license of Stack Overflow, I license this as CC-0 for anyone who needs this code in one of his projects.</sub>

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="GetDataFromOtherWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Open other window" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button Content="Get data from other window" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace GetDataFromOtherWindow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Window1? otherWindow;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            otherWindow = new Window1();
            otherWindow.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (otherWindow != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(otherWindow.GetData());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="GetDataFromOtherWindow.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="141" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox Name="richBox">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="This is some text"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace GetDataFromOtherWindow
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string GetData()
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
                richBox.Document.ContentStart,
                richBox.Document.ContentEnd
            );
            return textRange.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is not very MVVM-friendly, because this code has no model which would know about the business logic.

As per the comments, if you want to show the data after closing Window1, you can do this:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace GetDataFromOtherWindow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var otherWindow = new Window1();
            otherWindow.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show(otherWindow.GetData());
        }
    }
}
```

Code for getting the data just before closing the window:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace GetDataFromOtherWindow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Window1? otherWindow;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (otherWindow != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(otherWindow.GetData());
            }

            base.OnClosing(e);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            otherWindow = new Window1();
            otherWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I show the text after closing directly `Window1`? Or must `Window1` be open to show the text?

Comment: You can also show it after closing the form. I updated the answer

Comment: But this code describes to open the `Window1` and show it as dialog. But can I make the code that the `Window1` sends the input when close to the `MainWindow`?

Comment: Who shall process the data when MainWindow is closed? Where do you want to send the data to? Well, it can process the data just before it's gone, if that's what you like

Comment: Can you show me an example how to send data from `Window1` before closing to `MainWindow`?

Comment: @githubhost2: yep. Done

Comment: I can’t run `GetValue` for the `TextBox`.

Comment: @githubhost2: There is no `GetValue()` in my code. You must have implemented that yourself.